# Getting rid of pre installed Office after installing Office 365 under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

It seems Windows now comes with a future-poor free version of Office pre-installed. After installing Office 365 this is causing lots of problems. 
E.g. links go to the pre-installed OneNote/Outlook etc. instead of the purchased 365 one. What makes it worse, is that they are hard to distinguish at first glance, which makes it very confusing and annoying. 
All instructions I've found are for removing all of Office. Do I really need to remove everything and then re-install and setup Office 365? Surely, many Office 365 users must have this issue, but I fail to find an answer on the web.

Answer (score 1):

What's is the detailed version of pre-installed Office version and new purchased Office 365? Office 365 ProPlus, Office 365 Home and Business?

Generally, it is recommended to keep one Office version on one computer. If you want to keep all Office version, you need to set the default programs to your wanted Office application on Windows:

Control Panel > Default Programs > Set your default programs.

Comment: Thanks. I cant answer your question anymore, since I've re-installed a stripped down version of Windows 10 that was provided by my university. It came without office and I now installed Office 365 (Business I suppose). 
Anyway, how shall I proceed with this thread? Delete? Mark your answer as  accepted? Thanks again!